# Splitting lists to make dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am fairly new at programming and I'm trying to practice making lists and dictionaries. I have a list that contains numbers and letters separated by a colon

```
lst = ['1:A', '2:B', '3:C', '4:A']
```

and I want to make a dictionary that looks like this

```
dictionary = {'1':'A', '2':'B', '3':'B', '4':'A'}
```

so that the key matches the number and the value matches the letter. I thought I could just make a nested list or something but I just couldn't get it to work. What is the best way to turn this type of list into a dictionary as stated?

Comment: Don't name a variable `list`; it masks the built-in type.

Comment: Ok. That was just a example name. I normally use something like 'mylist'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`dict()` constructor](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) with a generator expression:

```
dict(v.split(':') for v in lst)
```

This works because `dict()` accepts a sequence of (key, value) pairs as input; each `str.split()` call produces these from the elements in your list.

Demo:

```
>>> lst = ['1:A', '2:B', '3:C', '4:A']
>>> dict(v.split(':') for v in lst)
{'1': 'A', '3': 'C', '2': 'B', '4': 'A'}
```

Comment: I knew there was a super easy way to this. Thanks! I need to learn more about generator expressions. I've only used them a little.